# Error using range to iterate over json secrets

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The looping of `Values.secret` is not working properly, how do I loop through various json secrets?

The error:

```
Deploy failed: The Deployment "master-micro-automated-customer-contact" is invalid:

spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[2].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when value is not empty
spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[3].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when value is not empty
spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[4].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when value is not empty
spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[5].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when value is not empty
spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[6].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when value is not empty
spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[8].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when value is not empty
spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[9].valueFrom: Invalid value: "": may not be specified when value is not empty
```

deployment.yaml

```
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: docker-registry-pull-secret
containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    image: "{{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.tag }}"
    imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.imagePullPolicy }}
    env:
      - name: RUNTIME_ENVIRONMENT
        value: {{ .Values.env }}
      {{ range $name, $value := .Values.env_variables -}}
      - name: {{ $name }}
        value: {{ $value }}
      {{ end }}
      {{ range $name, $value := .Values.secrets -}}
      - name: {{ $name }}
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: {{ $value }}
            key: {{ $name }}
      {{ end }}
```

values.yaml

```
secrets:
  AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_AAD_TOKEN_CREDENTIALS: azure-service-bus-credentials
  AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC_NAME: azure-service-bus-credentials
  AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME: azure-service-bus-credentials
  AZURE_TEST_DEV_URL: azure-service-bus-credentials
  CDATA_URL: cdata-credentials
  CDATA_TOKEN: cdata-credentials
  SALESFORCE_USERNAME: salesforce-credentials
  SALESFORCE_PASSWORD: salesforce-credentials

external-secrets:
  backendType: systemManager
  externalSecrets:
    - name: docker-registry-pull-secret
      secretType: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
      value:
        - key: /cluster/global/docker-registry-pull-secret
          name: .dockerconfigjson
    - name: azure-service-bus-credentials
      isJson: true
      value:
        - /cluster/azure-service-bus/credentials
    - name: cdata-credentials
      isJson: true
      value:
        - /cluster/cdata/credentials
    - name: salesforce-credentials
      isJson: true
      value:
        - /cluster/salesforce/credentials
```

secrets example

```
{
"AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_AAD_TOKEN_CREDENTIALS": "Endpoint=sb://data-dev-servicebus",
"AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_TOPIC_NAME": "XXXXX",
"AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME": "YYYYYY",
"AZURE_TEST_DEV_URL": "https://data-dev.azurewebsites.net
}
```

Comment: Do your values include any `env_variables`?  If you run `helm template` over your chart with those values, does it look okay?

Comment: And a more specific thing to try: does deleting the `-` at the end of the two `range` lines help?  (In the `helm template` output, I might expect see the `- name:` lines be unindented, though there's enough other whitespace that it's probably okay.)

Comment: Am I not missing a reference to the key in the secret json, I'm just supplying the secret name, no reference per say to to key itself?